# When does the boundary of a ball not equal to sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space, $a \in M, r > 0$, and the boundary of $B$<sub>r</sub>$(a)$ be non-empty. Under what conditions of this metric space, the boundary of $B$<sub>r</sub>$(a)$ does not equal to the sphere {x ∈ M : d (x, a) = r} ? In other words, how do we find such a metric space? I would appreciate any concrete examples.

Comment: Did you mean to have the condition that $B_r(a)$ is nonempty? (Asking because it is always the case: $a\in B_r(a)$.) If you, however, wanted the *boundary* of $B_r(a)$ to be nonempty, this is a whole another question, and @Mindlack 's comment does not apply.

Comment: The question in your post is not the same as the title, probably you're missing a "boundary of .." in the question?

Anyway, an example where the boundary of the open ball does not equal the sphere would be the open 1-ball in a discrete metric space $(M,d)$ (where $M$ has at least 2 elements), i.e. if $d(x,y)$ is $1$ iff $x\neq y$ and ($d(x,x) = 0$ follows from it being a metric). Then $B_1(x) := \{y \colon d(x,y) <1\} = \{x\}$, which is closed, so the boundary is empty, but the set $\{y \colon d(x,y) =1\}$ is $M\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop thank you for correcttion, definitely it should be the boundary of ball is non-empty

Comment: @J.Becker I meant to write the boundary of the ball is non-empty, I corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $M=(-\infty, 0]\cup\{1\}\subset\mathbb R$ with ordinary metric on $\mathbb R$. Then, $B_1(0)=(-1,0]$ and $\partial B_1(0)=\{-1\}$, but $S_1(0)=\{-1, 1\}$.

Comment: Pardon me but what does the symbol in front of B(0) means? Boundary?

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)#Common_definitions

Comment: 1 is not in the ball and that is why it is not in the boundary right?

Comment: To be in the boundary, every neighbourhood of $1$ (in particular, every ball centered in $1$ with nonzero radius) would need to have a nonempty intersection with $B_1(0)$. However, $B_1(1)\cap B_1(0)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{Z}$ under the metric it inherits as a subset of the Euclidean plane. The boundary of the open ball $B_1((0, 0))$ comprises the points $(\pm 1, 0)$, but the sphere of radius $1$ around $(0, 0)$ also includes the points $(0, \pm1)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the metric you mentioned? What is the boundary of that open ball? Also, (0, +-1) means (0,1) and (0, -1) right?

Comment: $d(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. I have said what the boundary is in the answer. And yes, I am using $(0, \pm 1)$ as a short-hand for $\{(0, 1), (0, -1)\}$.